# Let $p_1,\ldots,p_{n+1}\in \mathcal{P}_n$,$\quad p_i(0)=0,\space i=1,\ldots,n+1$. Prove that $p_1,\ldots,p_{n+1}$ are dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$p_1,\ldots,p_{n+1}\in \mathcal{P}_n \\
p_i(0)=0, \quad \forall i=1,\ldots,n+1$$ 
prove that $p_1,\ldots,p_{n+1}$ are dependent.

**My reasoning:**

Assuming independence, then $p_1,\ldots,p_{n+1}$ are also a base for $\mathcal{P}_n$, because $1,t,\ldots,t^n$ are a base for $\mathcal{P}_n$ and every base has the same number of elements. then choose $a_i,\space i=1,\ldots,n+1$ such that
$$1=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_ip_i.$$
But given $p_i(0)=0$, this is not possible at zero and $p_1,\ldots,p_{n+1}$ will not span $\mathcal{P}_n$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Thanks, for verification